# Pip Value Calculation

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate the pip value. There is [an online calculation](https://www.mataf.net/en/forex/tools/pip-value) that did it. There is only one script "© Investoz Pip Value Calculator FX" that did it, but the source is not available.

I attempted to do it, but my example works only on FOREX pairs with base currency USD, e.g. USDCAD, USDJPY, etc. How can I do that for all FOREX pairs?

```
f_pipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)

float _pipValue = (f_pipSize() * 100000) / close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For pairs with USD as the quote currency e.g. AUDUSD and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10

**For pairs with CAD as the quote currency e.g. EURCAD and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10 / current close of the USDCAD

**For pairs with CHF as the quote currency e.g. USDCHF and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10 / current close of the USDCHF

**For pairs with AUD as the quote currency e.g. GBPAUD and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10 / current close of the AUDUSD

**For pairs with NZD as the quote currency e.g. AUDNZD and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10 / current close of the NZDUSD

**For pairs with GBP as the quote currency e.g. EURGBP and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = 10 / current close of the GBPUSD

**For pairs with JPY as the quote currency e.g. USDJPY and account currency of USD:**

Pip value of 1 lot = (10 / current close of the USDJPY) * 100

I read about it from this site and another one that I forgot:
https://www.thebalance.com/calculating-pip-value-in-forex-pairs-1031022